# Does remoteconfig fetch all the keys again?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config

On calling FetchAsync() in unity, does it download the complete data set again or only the changes i.e. key-value pairs.

I tried using fiddler to get the response but surprisingly, no session were logged for firebase. I tried to get the size of the data usage tab in android, but I was getting a spike of 1 mb for a mere change of 1 key-value pair.

Answer (score 1):

When a fetch can no longer be satisfied by local cache, it will download the entire set of keys and values.  There are no incremental or delta updates like there are for the Firebase database options.

Comment: Is there any test to confirm this?

Comment: I think your observations are already the test.  You observed a large data spike when you expected a small one.